# How can I guard a Docker container so that it's always running?

Tags: docker, services, background-process

I have a HBase Docker container that's running on several developers laptops. When the developers close their laptops, the Docker container will invariably die and stop running.

This is how we're invoking the container:

```
$ docker run -d --hostname hbase-db --name hbase \
     -p 2181:2181   -p 8080:8080   -p 8085:8085   -p 9090:9090 -p 9095:9095 \
     -p 16000:16000 -p 16010:16010 -p 16201:16201 -p 16301:16301 \
     harisekhon/hbase
```

#### Question

How can I guard this container so that it'll restart automatically when/if it dies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Docker restart policies

Docker provides a feature that solves this issue called [Docker restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/):

> Docker provides [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart) to control whether your containers start automatically when they exit, or when Docker restarts. Restart policies ensure that linked containers are started in the correct order. Docker recommends that you use restart policies, and avoid using process managers to start containers.

The types of restart policies:

```
no                  Do not automatically restart the container. (the default)

on-failure          Restart the container if it exits due to an error, which
                    manifests as a non-zero exit code.

unless-stopped      Restart the container unless it is explicitly stopped or 
                    Docker itself is stopped or restarted.

always              Always restart the container if it stops.
```

#### Usage

You can then use it the restart policy like this:

```
$ docker run -dit --restart always redis
```

#### Considerations

> - A restart policy only takes effect after a container starts successfully. In this case, starting successfully means that the container is up for at least 10 seconds and Docker has started monitoring it. This prevents a container which does not start at all from going into a restart loop.
> - If you manually stop a container, its restart policy is ignored until the Docker daemon restarts or the container is manually restarted. This is another attempt to prevent a restart loop.
> - Restart policies only apply to containers. Restart policies for swarm services are configured differently. See the flags related to service restart.

#### Example

Here we're going to use the [hello-world Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/) to illustrate how this works.

To start we pull it down:

```
$ docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/hello-world ...
latest: Pulling from docker.io/library/hello-world
9db2ca6ccae0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4b8ff392a12ed9ea17784bd3c9a8b1fa3299cac44aca35a85c90c5e3c7afacdc
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/hello-world:latest
$
```

With our container downloaded, let's run it:

```
$ docker run -dit --restart always hello-world
0f6a61dddd3b667727a20df2c198941b2202653a71b6c86b8ace7b236bafc974
```

And if we run a couple of `docker ps` we'll see it restarting over and over:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                              PORTS               NAMES
0f6a61dddd3b        hello-world         "/hello"            27 seconds ago      Up Less than a second                                   upbeat_brown

...time passes...

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                              PORTS               NAMES
0f6a61dddd3b        hello-world         "/hello"            5 minutes ago       Restarting (0) About a minute ago                       upbeat_brown

...time passes...
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
0f6a61dddd3b        hello-world         "/hello"            10 minutes ago      Restarting (0) 3 minutes ago                       upbeat_brown
```

Looking the the Docker logs we can see that it's restarted multiple times:

```
$ docker logs 0f6a61dddd3b -f | grep "Hello from Docker"
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
Hello from Docker!
```

When you're all done, be sure to stop the container so it doesn't restart forever:

```
$ docker stop 0f6
0f6
```

#### Your fix

To solve your issue simply run your HBase Docker container like so:

```
$ docker run -d --hostname hbase-db --name hbase --restart always \
    -p 2181:2181   -p 8080:8080   -p 8085:8085   -p 9090:9090   -p 9095:9095 \
    -p 16000:16000 -p 16010:16010 -p 16201:16201 -p 16301:16301 \
    harisekhon/hbase
```

#### References

- [Start containers automatically](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)

Comment: Can this be used in docker-compose?

Comment: @Ezwig - of course - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/.

Comment: Excellent +1. Is there way so that we can start another docker container for the same docker image, rather than restarting the same (stopped/failed) docker container? @slm